# .htaccess file in azure app url rewriting

Tags: php, azure, iis, url-rewriting

I have a single page application developed in Php angular mySql. It uses a rest api class to get the data from mysql db.

Application works fine in a shared hosting with cPanel (linux). I copied the files in Azure app service but I cannot get it to work. I get the following message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I understand it is running IIS and IIS does not support .htaccess file which is rewriting the url .

the contents of .htaccess are :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

If have done some study and changed the .htaccess to web.config but still do not get it to work.

My web.config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
            <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.webServer>
    <security>

    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension=".php" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
            <add extension=".html" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="14:00:00:00" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="rule 1K" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/php/services/api.php?x={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <remove value="index.php" />
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>



</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Dose your php api application in the `/php/services/` folder in the root directory? And dose it work fine if you delete the `web.config` and directly browse the php api application?

Answer (score 1):

According the content of your web.config, all the requests will be rewrote to the `php/services/api.php` script under the root directory. So could you make sure there is the script exist in the path.

Additionally, according the error message you get, usually, when we get this message, that means there are something wrong about the code on your server.

Per my experience, maybe you miss any dependencies required in your PHP scripts. You can login the KUDU console site of your web app to check the application's completeness. The URL of Kudu console site should be `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.